# how to extract data from body for web scraping after requests.get()

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

here is my code

```
    SUSTAINABILITY = []
    
    response = requests.get(URL, timeout=15)
    page_src = response.text
    SUSTAINABILITY.append(page_src.count("sustainability"))
```

I am getting the HTML response from response.text and then I am checking how many times the word sustainability shows up. This code is working but I only want to count the word "sustainability" inside the body tag.

How can i extract data from the body tag and then do count() to see how many times the word "sustainability" occur?

Comment: You should probably use html parser, such as `beautifulsoup` and parse the text from tags of interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@andrej-kesely get a good advice.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests


response = requests.get(URL, timeout=15)
# Make a "soup" from the response's text
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
# Take the <body> of HTML page as NavigableString (if I don't miss),
# convert it into string and count required string
print(str(soup.body).count("a"))
```